# str.split() fails randomly?

Tags: javascript, string

this code fails randomly when input comes from specific sources, it works usually OK:

```
var str = input;
var lines = str.split("¤");
var map = {};
for(var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {  var pieces = lines[i].split("=");  
map[pieces[0]] = pieces[1];}
```

for example this input data does not create MAP at all, there is just one map entry:

```
"[core]¤student_id=teach54yuy63v¤student_name=Demo, teacher¤credit=c¤lesson_location=¤lesson_status=n,a¤path=¤score=¤time=00:00:00¤[Core_Lesson]¤tmreal_status=n,a¤tmreal_score=¤¤¤[Core_Vendor]¤¤[Objectives_Status]¤¤"
```

this data works:

> [core]¤student_id=169yyuy63v¤student_name=,
>   Si¤credit=c¤lesson_location=1¤lesson_status=n,a¤path=¤score=¤time=00:00:00¤[Core_Lesson]¤real_status=i¤real_score=¤talhits=int:

Comment: Could be a character encoding problem. What encodings are `str` and your JavaScript source file?

Comment: To start with, you could try using 'String.fromCharCode(yourseparator)' instead of pasting the character into html and see if that works.

Comment: problem seem to appear with UTF8 page

Answer (score 1, accepted):

It has to do with encoding. Maybe some resources use ASCII, some UTF. Convert, or make sure all resources have the same encoding.

Answer (score 1):

You get an error when you try to access the second item from splitting "[core]" on "=".

You would need a check after splitting on "=" that you actually got a key and a value.

```
var str = input;
var lines = str.split("¤");
var map = {};
for (var i = 0; i < lines.length; i++) {
   var pieces = lines[i].split("=");
   if (pieces.length == 2) {
      map[pieces[0]] = pieces[1];
   }
}
```

Answer (score 1):

try to use \xA4

it's the charCode of '¤'